# Solution needed for outputting status of processed files with MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory, progress

I have to functions for handling processing of files in a directory.

One function reads and counts the files in the directory and foreach file it calls a function that does some action on that file.

What i need is how to update a DIV tag everytime a file is processed. The files are done in sync and is startet by calling the first function.

Right now i return a partialview, but it first return when alle the files are done. As there can be up to 1000 files, i would like to give the user somekind of progress information.

Kind regards
\T

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of [Copying file file with a progress status.](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx). You can modify this as per your requirement.
If you wish to show the progress you can use ajax or JSON with a jQuery timer which requests number of files of destination folder.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I have different infomation i need to tell the user. Like "files moved", conversion 1 done, conversion 2 done... And i have the function for duing the different things, i "just" need some way to update the DIV tag after each step